# How to pass row index through onchange function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table and each row contains select tag.

```
 <table>
   <tr>  
     <td><select onchange="function(this.value)">
           <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
        </select>
      <td>
 </tr>
<tr>  
     <td><select onchange="function(this.value)">
           <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
        </select>
      <td>
 </tr>
<table>
```

I want to pass the row index to the function(). How can it done?

Comment: `$(this).closest('tr').index()`

Comment: @ArunPJohny: ahh... index. i confused it with eq

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse to `tr` element using closest along with `.index()` to get its index:

```
 $(this).closest('tr').index()
```